# int (*number)[2] returns a 2D array or an array of 2 elements? C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm confused if int (*number)[2]; in C returns A) a multi-dimensinonal array with each subarray containing 2 elements OR B) an array of 2 elements ? As I read through some previous questions, the consensus is that it returns an array of 2 elements. However, looking at this example, the answer seems otherwise:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int arr[3][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
    int (*number)[2]; 
    
    number = arr; 

    printf("First element: %d %d\n", (*number)[0], (*number)[1]); // prints "1 2"
    number++; 
    
    printf("Second element: %d %d\n", (*number)[0], (*number)[1]); // prints "3 4"

    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody clarify this case and possibly point me to the related document? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Paste your declaration into cdecl.org. It will translate it to English.

Comment: `number` is a pointer to an array of 2 elements.

Comment: @Barmar No it will not. https://cdecl.org/?q=int+arr%5B3%5D%5B2%5D+%3D+%7B%7B1%2C+2%7D%2C+%7B3%2C+4%7D%2C+%7B5%2C+6%7D%7D%3B Stop recommending that broken crap site already. It is nowhere close to understanding common C code, let alone in a state where it could explain it in English...

Comment: It is a pointer. You can never distinguish whether it points to one element or an array of elements. In this case, the elements are of type `int[2]`. Whether there is one array[2] or multiple array[2]s depens on the memory you let it point to. In the same way you cannot tell if a `char*` points to a single character or a string.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not familiar with the site but it does parse the example correctly.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Maybe a browser thing then. In Firefox I got `syntax errorbad character '='bad character '{'bad character '{'bad character '}'bad character '{'bad character '}'bad character '{'bad character '}'bad character '}'` when pasting the OP's 2D array declaration (which is far from exotic). Regardless, a site which doesn't accept one of the major browsers is still a broken crap site.

Comment: @Lundin Apparently, initializations are not supported (e.g. `int i=3;` fails as well). I meant that `int (*number)[2]; ` works.

Comment: @Lundin Cdecl only understands declarations without initialisations. If you try with `int arr[3][2];` it translates it to "declare arr as array 3 of array 2 of int", which is reasonable. In any case I'm not aware of better tools, so I'm afraid we have to stick to it.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica As every beginner knows, initialization is an optional part of the declaration syntax. But it doesn't understand VLA declarations either. Nor does it understand super basic stuff like `static const int x;`. Crap tool, period.

Answer (score 2):

- `int arr[3][2]` is an array of 3 `int [2]` items.
- `int (*number)[2];` is a pointer to an `int [2]` item. And as such suitable at pointing into the above array.
- `number = arr;`  sets it to point at the first item in that array, since `arr` "decays" into a pointer to its first item in this expression.
- `*number` gives the pointed-at array. `(*number)[0]` gives the first item in that array.
- `number++` means that `number` will point to the next array item in the array of 3 `int [2]` items.

Answer (score 1):

```
int (*number)[2];
```

declares a pointer to an array of 2 integers.

```
int arr[3][2]
```

declares a 2-dimensional array, whose rows are arrays of 2 integers.

```
number = arr;
```

is equivalent to

```
number = &arr[0];
```

(see [What is array-to-pointer conversion aka. decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay)) so now `number` points to the first row of `arr`.

After `number++`, it points to the second row of `arr`.